# Ajuda com sessão em PHP

Tags: php, session, slim

Bom dia!

Tenho um sistema em php onde utilizo uma webservice para realizar consultas, e salvo seu retorno na sessão para poder utilizar via ajax.

Até aí tudo bem, o problema é quando preciso fazer duas ou mais consultas simultâneas, exemplo:

Abro duas abas no navegador é realizo duas consultar diferentes, após o retorno da webservice salvo seus dados na sessão:

```
Consulta 1: Session::set('consulta', $consulta);
Consulta 2: Session::set('consulta', $consulta);
```

Quando a consulta 2 é gravada na sessão ela sobrescreve a consulta 1, pois, o nome que estou passando para a sessão é o mesmo.

Eu poderia trocar o nome da sessão gerando um número random ou passando algum parâmetro que corresponde com essa consulta, exemplo:

```
Consulta 1: Session::set('consulta1', $consulta);
Consulta 2: Session::set('consulta2', $consulta);
```

Mas o problema real está nas chamadas ajax, hoje realizo chamadas ajax para meu arquivo php que lé a sessão `Session::get('consulta')`, como que faço para que o ajax acesse essa sessão se eu alterar o nome da sessão para cada pesquisa?

Teria como fazer uma sessão por aba do navegador, tipo o @ViewScoped do JSF do java. Ou se tem alguma outra forma sem uso de sessão?

Obs:
Posso ter até 10 pesquisas simultâneas, o que seriá 10 pesquisas salvas na sessão.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que você pode fazer da seguinte forma, na sua sessão de consulta você vai armazenar um array de consultas e não apenas uma consulta. Sempre que você fizer uma nova consulta, você pega o valor da sua sessão, incrementa a nova consulta nesse valor e seta pra sessão o `array` atualizado, assim você não vai sobrescrever  o valor atual. Com isso a sua consulta ajax não precisa alterar o nome da consulta, você só vai precisar tratar para pegar a última posição do `array` de consultas.

Abstração do código.

```
// Aqui é sua sessão com a primeira consulta
$_SESSION['consulta'] = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'nome' => 'Teste'
    ]
];

// Aqui é o que você vai fazer quando a 2 consulta for executada
$consultas_antigas = $_SESSION['consulta'];
$nova_consulta = $consulta; // Aqui você executa sua query ou que for necessário para gerar sua consulta

// Agora você atribui para a sessão o array das consultas antigas mesclado com a nova consulta
$_SESSION['consulta'] = array_push( $consultas_antigas, $nova_consulta );
```

Comment: Entendi sua lógica, mas fiquei com um ponto em questão que é o seguinte: você mencionou para tratar o ajax para pegar á última posição do array, mas supondo que tenho duas pesquisas abertas, a segunda pesquisa vai funcionar perfeitamente pegando á última posição do array, mas como faria para que o ajax pegasse sua respectiva consulta dentro do array se ele não estiver na última posição? Como, por exemplo, as pesquisas antigas.

Comment: Não consegui entender muito bem sua questão, você quer dizer tipo assim, vc fez 2 consultas e funcionou blz, ai agora vc quer pegar a consulta número 1 de novo, que no caso ela já é antiga. Seria isso?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo.

Comment: Pensei aqui em 2 possibilidades, a primeira você add um parâmetro ao seu ajax, por exemplo o ID da consulta, e assim vc consegue localizar ela dentro do array. A segunda é sempre que você fizer uma consulta, antes de você mesclar o que já existe com a nova consulta, vc verifica se a mesma já existe na sua sessão, se ela existir vc remove ela e a coloca como último item no array da sessão. Assim seu ajax vai continuar pegando o último item e vai funcionar em qualquer situação.